# ¿Cómo saber cual es el List group seleccionado?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un pequeño problema para saber cual es el list group seleccionado en una web hecha con PHP esencialmente.

[image]

En la parte izquierda se aprecia un list group, la idea es saber cual tengo seleccionado (ya sea por console.log o algo similar)...

Adjunto código a continuación:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="list-group" id="channel" name="channel" role="tablist">

          <?
          $query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM chat1 WHERE id_em='".$id."'  OR id_rec='".$id."' ");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
            ?>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="<?php echo $row["cod"]; ?>" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home"><?php echo $row["cod"]; ?></a>
         <?
     }
       ?>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">...1</div>

              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que hace es que simplemente hace un row al phpmyadmin y obtiene los códigos 171-170, 172-170 y 171-175.

Entonces yo tengo el siguiente js para identificarlo pero no funciona al parecer:

```
 $("#channel").click(function(){
   socket.emit('change channel',$("#channel").val());
});
```

Al hacer clic haga tal cosa.
Pero lo que sucede es que al hacer click funciona pero luego si quiero cambiar a otro código como el 171-170 por ejemplo, no los diferencia.

De hecho es lógico porque al decirle .click hace click en cualquiera y funciona, pero no los diferencia.

Antes hice un select option con esto mismo y en el código de js, puse el evento de en vez de .click, era .change(function()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar capturar el click en los `<a>` asi:

```js
$("#channel a").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="list-group" id="channel" name="channel" role="tablist">

          
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="171-170" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">172-170</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="172-170" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">172-170</a>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">...1</div>

              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: gracias! funcionó perfectamente